# Shall you await for a return value in an async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
async function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(f=>setTimeout(f, t))
}

async function delay100() {
    return await delay(100)  //  <---- do we need 'await' here?
}

async function main(){
    await delay100(); console.log('ok')
    await delay100(); console.log('ok')
    await delay100(); console.log('ok')
    await delay100(); console.log('ok')
}

main()
```

I do not see much difference, but wonder if awaiting on a an async return value in the async function is better to be performed or not? What would be the reasons to prefer one solution over another? Any performance, portability, usability or semantics considerations?

Comment: `return await` as the first and only line of a function seems a bit silly - you may as well just return the `Promise` itself. But, it does make sense if you also want to *handle* errors in that `async` function. (try/return await/catch)

Comment: @CertainPerformance valid point, error handling might differ between `main` and `delay100`, which would justify the (otherwise unnecessary) await in `delay100`.

Answer (score 3):

Practically, they're the same, since JS has auto-unwrapping of Promises. Use whichever you find more comfortable/more readable for yourself.

---

Having said that,

Semantically, with `await` you're returning `Promise<T>` whereas without `await` you're *semantically* returning `Promise<Promise<T>>`. (Again, to clarify, both would yield the exact same result and even the exact same return type in practice.)

Comment: And, as you said, JS will unwrap the `Promise<Promise<T>>` into `T` inside of `main` with the `await delay100()` (just for clarity)

Comment: @JayGould That is correct. I'm unsure of the specifics, it's even possible that just returning a Promise from an async function will auto unwrap it itself, even without the `await` on the other end.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha it won't unwrap itself without an `await`, it'll return an unresolved promise. `await` will unwrap the resolved promise when it resolves, otherwise the reference to the `unawaited` promise will be of type `Promise<T> (...resolving)`

Comment: No, what I mean is that it's possible that the `Promise<Promise<T>>` will get unwrapped to `Promise<T>` even without the `await`

Answer (score 0):

Well return before ahead will not make any difference but the await before you're calling function will make a difference.See the code snippets below.

```js
async function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(f=>setTimeout(f, t))
}

async function delay100(input) {
    return await delay(input)
}

async function main(){
    delay100(100).then(()=>console.log('ok1'));
    delay100(2000).then(()=>console.log('ok2'));
    delay100(140).then(()=>console.log('ok3'));
    delay100(160).then(()=>console.log('ok4'));
}

main()
```

```js
async function delay(t) {
        return new Promise(f=>setTimeout(f, t))
    }

    async function delay100(input) {
        return delay(input)
    }

    async function main(){
        await delay100(100).then(()=>console.log('ok1'));
        await delay100(2000).then(()=>console.log('ok2'));
        await delay100(140).then(()=>console.log('ok3'));
        await delay100(160).then(()=>console.log('ok4'));
    }

    main()
```